# Joining to table with multiple FKs and Rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT p.id, 
    p.firstname,
    **p.address1id,
    p.address2id,**
    r.invoice_id, 
    i.authcode

FROM    membershiprenewals r, 
    Profile p, 
    Invoice i

WHERE   r.orgID = 1 
    and r.period_id = 3
    and r.status = 0
    and r.profile_id = p.id 
    and r.invoice_id = i.id;
```

This table selects a Users Profile and a few related details.

A Profiles Addresses are stored in another table (profileaddress). And a Profile can have 2 addresses.  These addresses are referenced using p.address1 and p.address2.

I need to extend this query to join on the profileaddress table to get BOTH addresses and combined into the single record.

So the results I would need would be the following columns

```
p.id | p.firstname | .. etc .. | profileaddress1.address | profileaddress1.town | profileaddress2.address | profileaddress2.town | .. etc
```

I've been playing around with JOIN statements for hours, but just can't seem to crack it.

Any help hugely Appreciated !!

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  So, your query should be:

```
SELECT p.id, p.firstname, **p.address1id, p.address2id,**
       r.invoice_id, i.authcode
FROM membershiprenewals r JOIN
     Profile p
     ON r.profile_id = p.id JOIN
     Invoice i
     ON r.invoice_id = i.id
WHERE r.orgID = 1 AND r.period_id = 3 AND r.status = 0;
```

Then you want two joins to the address table:

```
SELECT p.id, p.firstname, p.address1id, p.address2id,
       pa1.address, pa1.town,
       pa2.address, pa2.town,
       r.invoice_id, i.authcode
FROM membershiprenewals r JOIN
     Profile p
     ON r.profile_id = p.id JOIN
     Invoice i
     ON r.invoice_id = i.id LEFT JOIN
     profileaddress pa1
     ON p.address1id = pa1.id LEFT JOIN
     profileaddress pa2
     ON p.address2id = pa2.id 
WHERE r.orgID = 1 AND r.period_id = 3 AND r.status = 0;
```

This uses `LEFT JOIN` in case one of the addresses is missing.

Comment: Gorden.. I dropped your query in and it just ran.  Exactly what I needed.  Thank you !!!  Can I ask why the explicit JOIN over commas?  Thanks again!